# Getting 401 from Postman but 200 from Swagger with Spring Boot Security and JWT

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, openapi, spring-security-rest

When I request APIs in POSTMAN protected by Spring Boot Security, I get the following error: **Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource** . But in Swagger, things are going well. These are my code in the following:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/save")
@Operation(summary = "save", security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth"))
public HttpStatus saveSeans(@RequestBody NewSeansRequestDto dto) {
    Seans seans = seansMapper.map(dto);
    seansRepository.save(seans);
    return HttpStatus.CREATED;
}
```

This my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**",
                        "/helpers/**",
                        "/roles/**",
                        "/films/**",
                        "/seans/**",
                        "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/v3/api-docs",
                        "/v3/api-docs/**",
                        "/swagger-resources",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui/**",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();

    }
}

public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            // get JWT (token) from http request
            String token = getJWTFromRequest(request);
            // validate token
            if (StringUtils.hasText(token) && jwtUtil.validateJwtToken(token)) {
                // get username from token
                String username = jwtUtil.getUsernameFromJwtToken(token);
                // load user associated with token
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                // set spring security
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJWTFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Component
public class JwtUtil {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(JwtUtil.class);

    @Value("${app.jwt-secret}")
    private String jwtSecretKey;
    private JwtParser createParser() {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(jwtSecretKey.getBytes())).build();
    }

    //get username from the Token
    public String getUsernameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        Claims claims = createParser().parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        return claims.getSubject();
    }

    //validate JWT token
    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            createParser().parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            LOG.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            LOG.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            LOG.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            LOG.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            LOG.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return new UserPrincipal(userRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(EmailNotFoundException::new));
    }

}

public class UserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    public UserPrincipal(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return mapToGrantedAuthority(user.getRoles());
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
    private Set<GrantedAuthority> mapToGrantedAuthority(Set<Role> roles) {
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}

each api that protected by spring boot security comes in the following class.

@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());

        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

        final Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("status", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        body.put("error", "Unauthorized");
        body.put("message", authException.getMessage());
        body.put("path", request.getServletPath());

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), body);
    }
}
```

I can't understand where I'm missing, everything has to work correctly. Because the front end programmer should not get a 401 error.

Comment: Are you sending the same headers? Can you check if there are any differences between Swagger (UI) and Postman requests?

Comment: What do you mean? I can't understand. How to send header in postman? and how can I differences between them?

Comment: In Postman I think you can use the console to check the actual request, https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/troubleshooting-api-requests/#debugging-in-the-console. For Swagger UI, the request can be found on the DevTools-> Network tab.

Comment: When accessing swagger did you not get a login popup the first time?